# Cascading SharePoint List Filter

Tags: list, filter, cascading

I have a list in my sharepoint site that has two columns I want to filter by on a webpage.  I want to have the first sharepoint list filter webpart to have the person select a Project Manager.  Than I want the second sharepoint list filter webpart to only list the Projects that are assigned to the Project Manager selected in the first sharepoint list filter.  Once the person selects the project in the second sharepoint list filter It will update a list view with information about the selected project.  I can't figure out how to set the connections to make this cascading work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://site name/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://sitename/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function ()  
{  
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "Employee",  
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  
        parentColumn: "Company",  
        childColumn: "Employee",  
        debug: true  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

Put that script in a script editor web part and make necessary changes to those columns.